# Do tag synonyms show up somewhere?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I suggested a [tag synonym](https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). I wonder if this shows up somewhere (other than in the linked page)? As far as I can tell, this does not appear in the review menu:

[image]

Not that we have too many of them, but I am interested to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be that is shows up on the tag synonym page, where people are supposed to go and vote on proposals. This means proposals aren't very visible (who sits staring at the tag synonym page?) This "feature" of the site is subject to various debates over on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) ([e.g. here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138832/tag-synonyms-approval-process), [or here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work), [or here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278126/how-do-you-actually-get-a-synonym-approved)), but we can't do much here other than participate in that debate because these kinds of design things are set as network-level policy rather than at the site-level.

For now I have exercised moderator privilege and approved the synonym you proposed. If you see any other synonyms that are needed then you can propose them and post about them on meta.

Comment: Great, thanks!!